XSLT template condition based on xml tag to update XML string tag
I have a unique issue with XSLT 1.0. Below is my input XML.
XML:
<request>        
    <xml>
        <![CDATA[<format>1</format><account>5024734061</account><amount>$118.23</amount><dueDate>07/15/2024</dueDate>]]>
    </xml>
    <credit>Y</credit>
    <debit>N</debit>
</request>

And Output XML :
Based on the value of credit or debit tag as Y, It should show amount as Credit: $118.23  or Debit: $118.23 as tag.
if the credit tag has value Y , then the XML string tag should have tag as credit and followed by amount as shown below:
<xml>
    <![CDATA[<format>1</format><account>5024734061</account><credit>$118.23</credit><dueDate>07/15/2024</dueDate>]]>
</xml> 



Please format the codes in your question properly. 2. Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? This task could be easier to solve with some extension functions, if your processor supports them.


This is the XML :

<format>1</format><account>5024734061</account><amount>$118.23</amount><dueDate>07/15/2024</dueDate>

Y
N


It is an embedded processor , so I have access only to xslt. It is failing in condition for checking whether credit tag is Y or N

Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Please identify the processor - see here how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

To do this in pure XSLT 1.0 you would have to do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/request">
    <xml>   
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="normalize-space(xml)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="'amount'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="name((credit|debit)[.='Y'])"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search-string)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$search-string"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="$replace-string"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

This is of course assuming that the original xml payload does not contain the search-string "amount" anywhere else other than in the amount "element" name.

This is parsing the inner XML "by hand" which is always a bit of a desperate measure, because there will always be some inputs on which it fails (as you point out).

@MichaelKay True, it is a bit of a hack. But the only alternative in XSLT 1.0 is to save the inner "XML" to a file using disable-output-escaping and then process it by another XSLT. I doubt very much this option is available to the OP using "an embedded processor", and it doesn't seem like they expect an input that will not satisfy the stated assumption.
